# How do I create an instance of the TabLayout class programmatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-tablayout

I want to create an instance of the [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) class programmatically for instrumentation testing purposes. Sadly, the [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) constructor is throwing an [IllegalArgumentException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException) with the following message:

> The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).

This is what I've tried:

```kotlin
val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
val tabLayout = TabLayout(context)
```

I've tried `TabLayout(context, null, R.style.Theme_AppCompat)` as well but no luck.

What do I need to do to create an instance of the [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) class when the theme of my context is not `Theme.AppCompat` or a descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper) as follows:

```kotlin
val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
val tabLayout = TabLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat))
```